# How to do multiple filter in Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js, frontend, vuejs2

Im trying to use multiple filters but it's not working here is my code.
It's not making it to lowercase it just removes spaces.

EDIT:

For the lowercase I want to use Vue js filter [lowercase](http://011.vuejs.org/api/filters.html)

```
<div class="col-md-4" :class="playerBio.current_team | lowercase | removespace ">
```

JS

```
    removespace( str ) {
        if( str ) {
            return str.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code of your filters.

Comment: Your link is for Vue1. Are you sure that ask about [vuejs2]? In Vue2 you can chain [filters](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Filters)

Comment: @KirillMatrosov sorry about that link in Vue1, but I'm currently using Vue 2 how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myText: 'Hello There Vue'
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs['div']) // log this div
  },
  filters: {
    lowercase: function(value) {
      return value.toLowerCase()
    },
    removespace: function(value) {
      return value.replace(/\s/g, '')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<div class="col-md-4" :class="myText | lowercase | removespace" ref="div"></div>
</div>
```

I edited my first answer, because it appears `filter`s can be used with `v-bind` as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

@PenAndPapers, you should write your own filter for **lowercase**, because there is no ready filters in vers 2.

```js
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
     cls: "cL ass"
    },
    filters: {
      lowercase: function (value) {
        if (!value) return ''
        value = value.toString()
        return value.toLowerCase();
      },
      removespace( str ) {
          if( str ) {
              return str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
          }
      }
    }
})
```

```css
.class
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    {{cls | lowercase | removespace}}
    <div v-bind:class='cls | lowercase | removespace'></div>
</div>
```